# angular validation .error not defined

Tags: javascript, html, angular, validation

I'm trying to use a template driven form and I can't seem to get the errors property to correctly work to validate the minlength as per the tutorial [Here](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#simple-template-driven-forms).  The error I'm getting on page load in the dev tools is:

> ContactFormComponent.html:8 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'minlength' of null

So the problem is that there is no `.error` property on the ngModel.  I'm not sure if I've misinterpreted something or incorrectly set up the form.  Without the validation everything works as intended.

HTML

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #contactForm="ngForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input minlength="6" maxlength="50" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" required email [(ngModel)]="contactForm.email" #email="ngModel">
        <div *ngIf="email.dirty || email.touched" class="alert alert-danger">
            <div [hidden]="!email.errors.minlength">
                <span>Email is too short</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Component

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Contact } from './contact';
import { AppService } from '../app.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'selected-page',
  template: require('./contact-form.html'),
  providers: [AppService]
})

export class ContactFormComponent {
    contactForm = new Contact();
    submitted: boolean = false;

    constructor (private appService: AppService) {}

    onSubmit() {
        this.appService.emailContact(contactForm).then(data => {
            this.submitted = true;
        });
    }
}
```

Module

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule, Routes }   from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { ContactFormComponent } from './contact/contact-form.component';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'contact',
        component: ContactFormComponent
    }
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule
    ],
    declarations: [ 
        AppComponent,
        ContactFormComponent,
    ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    providers: [ AppService ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Why don't you just `<div [hidden]="!email.errors?.minlength">`?

Comment: @TheUnreal Yea this works thanks. Got me on the right track to narrowing down that I was using the *ngIf incorrectly in another part of my code aswell. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I was using `*ngIf` in my code incorrectly and made assumptions about how it worked.  I updated my original post to correctly reflect this.

The `*ngIf` on `email.errors` stops the child html elements from being evaluated which stops the error from happening.

As per TheUnreals comment you can also not use `*ngIf` all together by doing `!email.errors?.minlength`.

What I had

```
<div *ngIf="email.dirty || email.touched" class="alert alert-danger">
    <div [hidden]="!email.errors.minlength">
        <span>Email is too short</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Correct Answer

```
<div *ngIf="email.errors && (email.dirty || email.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
    <div [hidden]="!email.errors.minlength">
        <span>Email is too short</span>
    </div>
</div>
```